# can a nodejs application developed and build on linux environment can also be build on windows

Tags: node.js

I have a nodejs web application with angularJS in frontend which was developed and build on linux earlier but now I need to build it in windows and proceed my development. Is it possible. If yes then what will be the required steps and what will be the dependencies i need to install.

Can I run this application through Visual studio 2015 by importing it. If yes what will be the process. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Node is scripting language, Just install nodejs on windows and run your script.

Comment: Technically node.js is an interpreted language vs. a compiled